# How to accurately estimate the start of an increasing value of a variable in time?

Tags: r

## Goal

I have brake force (kg) data for many drivers, and I want to find when the brake application started in time. Particularly, I need the time frame of brake start. Following are three examples of brake pedal force and the desired location of the brake start of time frames:

[image]

## Estimating Brake start

I estimated the brake start by assuming that it is a changepoint. So, I used the `changepoint` package in `R`. But I get some of them right and others wrong (the vertical red line below represents the estimated changepoint):

[image]

You can see the changepoints for participants B and C are (almost) correct, but incorrect for participant A. In my full dataset, there are many incorrect values so manually estimating them is going to be very time consuming.

Do you have any suggestions to accurately estimate the brake start? Thank you for your time.

The data and code for the above figure are provided below.

### Data and Code

#### Data

```
foo <- structure(list(participant = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C"), frames = c(39614, 39644, 39674, 39704, 39734, 
39764, 39794, 39824, 39854, 39884, 39914, 39944, 39974, 40004, 
40034, 40064, 40094, 40124, 40154, 40184, 40214, 40244, 40274, 
40304, 40334, 40364, 40394, 40424, 40454, 40484, 40514, 40544, 
40574, 40604, 40634, 40664, 40694, 40724, 40754, 40784, 40814, 
40844, 40874, 40904, 40934, 40964, 40994, 41024, 41054, 41084, 
41114, 41144, 41174, 45296, 45326, 45356, 45386, 45416, 45446, 
45476, 45506, 45536, 45566, 45596, 45626, 45656, 45686, 45716, 
45746, 45776, 45806, 45836, 45866, 45896, 45926, 63792, 63822, 
63852, 63882, 63912, 63942, 63972, 64002, 64032, 64062, 64092, 
64122, 64152, 64182, 64212, 64242, 64272, 64302, 64332, 64362, 
64392, 64422, 64452, 64482, 64512, 64542, 64572, 64602, 64632, 
64662, 64692, 64722, 64752, 64782, 64812, 64842, 64872, 64902, 
64932, 64962, 64992, 65022, 65052, 65082, 65112, 65142, 65172, 
65202, 65232, 65262, 65292, 65322), ED_brake_pedal_force_kg = c(0.34, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.33, 0.33, 0.34, 0.32, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.32, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.37, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34, 
0.72, 2.01, 2.91, 4.57, 5.73, 5.84, 5.82, 5.21, 5.23, 5.23, 4.41, 
4, 3.57, 3.09, 2.28, 1.37, 0.33, 0.33, 0.65, 1.21, 3.36, 4.91, 
5.2, 5.96, 6.24, 7.6, 14.13, 25.8, 32.37, 37.71, 0.32, 0.34, 
0.33, 0.32, 1.72, 8.93, 18.83, 22.78, 39.5, 66.63, 9.46, 2.24, 
0.33, 0.34, 1.9, 5.5, 8.55, 10.66, 12.24, 12.24, 12.24, 12.27, 
0.29, 0.29, 0.31, 0.31, 0.3, 0.29, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.29, 0.3, 
0.31, 0.3, 0.29, 0.29, 0.91, 2.79, 3.67, 4.24, 5.61, 5.91, 6.08, 
5.4, 4.46, 3.74, 3.85, 4, 4.43, 2.08, 0.7, 0.3, 0.29, 0.31, 0.32, 
0.34, 0.69, 0.83, 0.83, 0.84, 1.36, 1.68, 2.04, 3.87, 5.21, 7.28, 
9.84, 13.49, 14.83, 14.79, 14.79, 14.79, 14.71)), row.names = c(NA, 
-127L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### Code

Estimation of changepoint and plotting:

```
library(changepoint)
library(tidyverse)
foo %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  mutate(brake_start_frame = frames[cpts(cpt.meanvar(ED_brake_pedal_force_kg, 
                                                     Q = 8, 
                                                     method = "BinSeg"))][1]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = frames, y = ED_brake_pedal_force_kg)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = brake_start_frame), color="red") +
  facet_wrap(~ participant, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Try the `cpt.meanvar(... method = "PELT")` (without `Q=8)` and `cpt.mean(... method = "PELT")`. There is also the `gratia` package for change in derivatives. Also, since you seem to have a window of small values with little variance at the start of each series, you could maybe do something simple like find the first value that is greater than 1 SD of that window (or some such)? Change point methods sometimes struggle on curves in my experience but seems to work here so may be adequate :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65476628/6574038

Comment: sorry, for cpt.meanvar(... method = "PELT") use `param.est` to see the magnitude of changes in the mean and variance to determine which change point location is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a time-series problem, you can explore `TTR::momentum` function to solve this problem. Whenever momentum will go above a particular threshold in upward direction, it will trigger the event.

```
library(TTR)
library(data.table)
setDT(foo)
foo[, momentum := TTR::momentum(ED_brake_pedal_force_kg, 5), by = participant]

ggplot(foo) +
  geom_line(aes(x = momentum, y = ED_brake_pedal_force_kg)) +
  facet_wrap(~ participant, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Actually kinda cool :). Didn't know about that package when I did a bunch of ROC functions manually.....

Comment: Thank you! I get it now. When the value of `momentum` starts to increase from zero, that indicates the start of braking in this context. But in some cases the driver applies brakes multiple times. So the challenge is to correctly identify which one is the "brake start".